# Android Jetpack navigation optional argument is returning default value

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a Project with 2 screens a Home Screen that displays a list of recipes and a detail screen that display the recipe with more detail that the user clicked on. The problem I am having is that the recipeID that I attach to the route of the DetailScreen is not returning in savedStateHandle, Instead it is using the default value which is 0.

[Here is a link to my project on my github](https://github.com/Jonathan-Goris1/SpoonFed)
The problem can be found in App -> src -> main -> java/com/googleplaystore/spoonfed -> presentation -> navigation -> DetailNavGraph

[This is the detailnavGraph it shows the navigation call where the recipeId is attached to the route and also the composable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gG2nq.png)

[This is my AppNavHost, on line 25 you can see that I use the navigateToDetail function and I pass the recipeId to it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/192zq.png)

[This the recipeItem composable that gets the recipeId from the state and sets it val recipeId, recipeId is then passed up through other composable until it reaches the AppNavHost](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vrczq.png)

[This is my viewmodel, here you can see the saveStateHandle value on line 35 and also my api call function that takes the recipeId on line 48](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IoAPg.png)

Hopefully these images help better understand my problem.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please post your code as text, not as images. You can learn more here: [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you for providing a detailed explanation. I have compiled your project and identified the issue. The problem lies in the parsing of your navigateToDetail query. It should read `detail_screen?recipeId=3` instead of `detail_screen?recipeId={3}`.

To resolve this issue, please remove the curly braces and update the line of code as follows:

Replace:

```kotlin
this.navigate("${Screens.DetailScreen.route}?recipeId={$recipeId}")
```

With:

```kotlin
this.navigate("${Screens.DetailScreen.route}?recipeId=$recipeId")
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).